# GRUB problems... ugh

Tags: installation, dual-boot, grub2

I was experimenting with different distros of Ubuntu to put on a crappy old laptop for Pandora in my workshop and I decided that while I was waiting for parts to come (mainly a charger) I would try it on my desktop.

I ran the install, everything worked fine.  I rebooted, and everything looked nice and I chose Kubuntu as my OS for the laptop.  Later, I tried to reboot to my Ubuntu Studio installation, but found that it was no longer the default boot OS.  I figured, I can just take out the other HDD and all will be fine.

All was not fine.  I had forgotten that I had removed the HDD (I was testing it the next day) and I panicked.  I scoured the forums and figured out what had happened.

What I was unable to find, though, was an *EXTREMELY EASY* way to move the GRUB to the old disk.

I have gotten pretty good with some aspects of Ubuntu over the last year or so, but I haven't messed with the GRUB, it was just something that always worked and I didn't need to dig into.  So, as a consequence, I am unsure of what to do on this problem.  I looked at other instructions, but I need something really clear and simple that explains what to do and *what the reason for doing those things is*.

A lot of tutorials fall short (in my eyes) when they don't explain why things are done.  They just say what to do, and it makes it harder to figure out what exactly is going wrong.

I am running Ubuntu Studio as my main audio workstation.  As stated before, I was trying out Kubuntu on that computer.  When I rebooted, it had moved the GRUB to the Kubuntu HDD.  It is not a major problem, just a bit of an annoyance when I turn on the computer and I would like to be able to take this HDD out of the computer.  I was just using it to test Kubuntu and it is only 40GB (Tiny and un-nessecary compared to my main 1TB drive).

Answer (score 1):

> What I was unable to find, though, was an EXTREMELY EASY way to move
>   the GRUB to the old disk.

**To Copy GRUB from one HDD to another**

Yes, this is extremely easy as one command in terminal.

First (to be sure) list the HDDs with the following command

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

it will results something like..

```
Disk /dev/sda: 120.0 GB, 120034123776 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 14593 cylinders, total 234441648 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0007329e

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    60289023    30143488   83  Linux
/dev/sda2        60289024    71774207     5742592   83  Linux
/dev/sda3        71774208   112734207    20480000   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 320.1 GB, 320072933376 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 38913 cylinders, total 625142448 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0001f627

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *        2048    81922047    40960000   83  Linux
/dev/sdb3        81924094   625141759   271608833    5  Extended
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sdb5        81926144   486234111   202153984   83  Linux
/dev/sdb6       486236160   621045759    67404800   83  Linux
/dev/sdb7       621047808   625141759     2046976   82  Linux swap / Solaris
```

as you can see in above example output, there are two disks. `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdb`. If I have GRUB in `/dev/sda` and I want **to copy it(install it)** to `/dev/sdb` I would boot from the HDD where the grub is installed (/dev/sda) and I would give this single command

```
sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sdb
```

Above method will copy the GRUB from the OS where you booted to the second HDD. In case you remove the OS from the first disk, it is possible to have problems with GRUB.

If you want to avoid above (possible) problems, you can attach the second HDD then boot from the OS where grub is handled (usually the latest installed OS) and do

```
sudo update-grub
```

GRUB scripts will recognize the other Linux OSs (in second HDD) and you will be able to boot on one of them. You can do that and then install the GRUB of a Linux OS (you prefer, that relies on second HDD) in the second HDD. That way you will avoid any future problems in case you remove an OS from the first HDD. The command is the same.

```
sudo grub-install --recheck /dev/sdb
```

Comment: I tried that.  It gives me "sudo: grub: command not found"

Comment: In Ubuntu or another Linux OS ? See the dash `-` . I edited the answer and I added a clarification and also the dash `-` (forgot it before. Sorry)

Comment: I tried that, all it did was update the GRUB.  I am going to edit the question, I don't think that I was clear about what my problem is.

Comment: Ok, do this and I will edit my answer. In case I don't know the answer I will remove it(my answer) completely.

Comment: i edited it.  Just a bit of info on the end

Comment: As I see the edit on your question now, maybe you must go to BIOS configuration page and change the order of the disks ? (first boot). Sometimes during installation of an OS the HDD boot order in BIOS can be change.

Comment: That doesn't help.  I did (sort of) that by removing the 40GB HDD with Kubuntu on it and it just sent the Ubuntu Studio install into a GRUB panic.  That was remedied by simply putting the other drive back.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12249/discussion-between-nikth-and-soundblastdj)